# Comparison of comma seperated string and updation of mysql column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php comma separated string  `$string = (a,b,c)`

I have a column in mysql that has items `(b,c,d)`
 I want to update the column as `(a,b,c,d)`

Comment: thanks for editing, now we can understand :)

Comment: Problems like this are why you shouldn't store lists in databases this way.

Comment: get the old value from the database, remove the parentheseses, explode the string into an array, merge the new values with the array, implode the array into a string, wrap it with parentheses, and then update the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't store multiple values in the database in one field - even though it's possible to do what you want, it's very inefficient.  Think about normalising your schema and using one-to-many relationship with two tables.

If you must however, then you can have something like the below.  Note that you **must add error handling** to this code.

```
//connect to the database and read existing data
$dbh = new PDO(CONNECT_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
$dbs = $dbh->query("select data_string from my_table where id=1");
$row = $dbs->fetch(PDO:FETCH_NUM);
$dbs->closeCursor();

//strip parentheses and convert string to array
$cur_data = str_getcsv(substr($row[0], 1, -1));

//strip parentheses and convert new data to array
$string = "(a,b,c)";
$add_data = str_getcsv(substr($string, 1, -1));

//merge existing and new data eliminating duplicates
$new_data = array_unique(array_merge($cur_data, $add_data));

//create new csv string for the merged data
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
ob_start();
fputcsv($output, $new_data);
fclose($output);
$value = ob_get_clean();

//update database table with new csv string with parentheses
$dbs = $dbh->prepare("update my_table set data_string=? where id=?");
$dbs->execute(array("($value)", 1));
$dbs->close();
```

See how much unnecessary work is required?  I really urge you to redesign your schema.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you wanted.

```
<?php
$string = "b, c, d";
$pieces = explode(",", $string);

for($index=count($pieces); $index>0; $index-- ){
    $pieces[$index] = $pieces[$index-1];
}

$pieces[0] = "a";
$string = implode(", ", $pieces);
echo $string;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '(a,b,c)';
$column = '(b,c,d)';

$string = substr($string, 1, -1);
$column = substr($column, 1, -1);

$string = explode(',', $string);
$column = explode(',', $column);

$result = array_unique(array_merge($string, $column), SORT_STRING);
$result = '(' . implode(',', $result) . ')';
```

Now you get the clue.